# calculate height of container with absolutely positioned children

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to calculate the height of a container which has children positioned absolutely? We can assume only direct children are positioned absolutely. Children have the same classes (no IDs) and are rotated, some are positioned using padding, like this:

```
<div class=my-view style="position: relative";>
<div class=my-child style="position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 10px; -webkit-transform: rotate(13deg);">
<div class=my-child style="position: absolute; padding-bottom: 5%; padding-left: 10%; -webkit-transform: rotate(-6deg);">
</div>
</div>
```

(for other browsers the transform tag looks different of course)

P.S. If it is necessary, children may have IDs

[Update]
Perhaps something like this code would work, but doesn't, because after the loop oTot.tot is zero ("tot" is like "total"):

```
  var oTot = { tot: 0 };  
  $(".my-view .my-child").each(function() {
    var h = $(this).outerHeight();
    var y = $(this).position().top + h;
    if (y > oTot.tot) {
      oTot.tot = y;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it solution.

```
var oTot = { tot: 0 };  
$(".my-child").each(function() {
    var h = $(this).outerHeight(),
        y = $(this).position().top + h;

    if (y > oTot.tot) {
      oTot.tot = y;
    }
});

console.log(oTot);
```

Comment: It gives too big number. That's because the height of the container is not equal to the sum of heights of its children, because the children are not one below the other, they are positioned absolutely. I think it's necessary to check the top+height value of the child inside the function and if it's bigger than in previous loop step, increase the max. I've written some code but it doesn't work, because after the loop the total is zero again. I'll put it at the end of my post.

Comment: You overrides object oTot, when called callback $.each. Therefore oTot becomes undefined. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/6cD94/1/

Comment: Yeah I figured it out already yesterday. I think your answer together with my updated algorithm give a picture how this can be done, depending on what somebody wants to achieve.